# I am trying to connect multiple docker containers and host machines to a consul server using weave network

Tags: docker, weave

The docker containers are running on different host machine that are running their separate docker deamons. So I am using weave network to connect them. The problem is I don't want to run the consul server on a docker conatiner, I want to run it on a host machine. So how do I add this host machine that is running consul server to a weave network so that other containers can register to consul server.

Comment: Do you need the added complexity of weave? (Tried it recently and decided to drop it) Why not just use consul for service discovery? Note there is a very useful registrator container that will auto-register docker containers with consul

Comment: @MarkO'Connor The problem is not with registering a container (registrator will do it easily). The problem is that I have servers running on host machine that are not containers. How to register these services and I don't want to run these services inside a container. I want my containers to be discoverable by these host machine using weave network.

Comment: Understood, but you accept that consul can track services not provided by a container? Since weave is designed to provide an overlay network, for containers, I don't know if normal host processes are supported. I also don't understand the benefits, which is why I queried your requirement.